# pyspark generate new column base on the interval value of a column to generate bucket of data

Tags: pyspark, intervals

I have a table like this

```
+------+------------+
| fruit|fruit_number|
+------+------------+
| apple|          20|
|orange|          33|
|  pear|          27|
| melon|          31|
|  plum|           8|
|banana|           4|
+------+------------+
```

And I want to generate a table like this

```
    |fruit_number_range|  number of types of fruit|
    |less than 5       |   1                      |
    |less than 25      |   3                      |
    |more than 25      |   2                      |
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate the new column based on the interval value of one column.

Here is the code how I generate the fruit table:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext,Row
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType,       StructType, StructField,LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, mean,col


rdd = sc.parallelize([('apple', 20),
('orange',33),
('pear',27),
('melon',31),
('plum',8),
('banana',4)])
schema = StructType([StructField('fruit', StringType(), True),
             StructField('fruit_number', IntegerType(),True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Comment: You could write UDF (user defined function) that counts the 3 buckets (<5, <25, >=25).  If the bucket is uniform e.g. 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, ... it's called histogram.  Google for Spark + histogram for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext,Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField,LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, mean,col, udf

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([('apple', 20),
                      ('orange',33),
                      ('pear',27),
                      ('melon',31),
                      ('plum',8),
                      ('banana',4)])
schema = StructType([StructField('fruit', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('fruit_number', IntegerType(),True)])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

def fruit_number_range(fruit_number):
    if fruit_number < 5:
        return 'less than 5'
    elif fruit_number < 25:
        return 'less than 25'
    return 'more than 25'

udf_fruit_number_range = udf(fruit_number_range, StringType())
df_w_range = df.withColumn("fruit_number_range", udf_fruit_number_range("fruit_number"))

df_w_range.groupBy("fruit_number_range").count().show()
```

Result

```
+------------------+-----+
|fruit_number_range|count|
+------------------+-----+
|      less than 25|    2|
|       less than 5|    1|
|      more than 25|    3|
+------------------+-----+
```

Comment: It works.  I used to register as TempTable and use case in sql to do this. This is a new way. Thanks